# CSS property with Condition

Tags: html, css, angular

I am working Angular Application. I need to display the color of the card according to the condition **without duplicating** (i.e) creating two cards and displaying with **hide** and **show** property.

**Example**

value of A can **yes** or **no** in Array

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-titile">Sample</div>
<div class ="card-body">
`
`
`             //Some codes
`
`
`
</div>
</div>
```

If value of A is yes I have to display this card in red and If no, I have to display it in yellow.

Comment: what you have to display?> the cardbody or tittle? what this A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[style.color]`

```
<div [style.color]="A == 'yes' ? 'red' : 'yellow'"></div>
```

If you want to add multi style use `ngClass`

```
 <div [ngClass]="A == 'yes' ? 'red' : 'yellow'"></div>
```

[See working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-trzqpf?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Comment: Its working. Can I know how to add multiple css property in that like border-radius, border-left-color

Answer (score 0):

Using an angular expression, add the contents of `A` as a class to the card. Then, with css, declare appropriately colored styles for those classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngClass in dom element like

```
<div [ngClass]="{'red-class': A === 'yes','yellow-class':A === 'no'}">
```

or you can also apply style conditionally like

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'color':A == 'yes' ? 'red' : 'yellow'}"></div>
```